# is there a way to remove leading and trailing zero in javascript without using regex?

Tags: javascript, performance, security, sonarqube

There's so many example in the web, about removing trailing and leading zeros.
but all of them are using regex.

```
sample.toString().replace(/^0+/,'').replace(/0+$/,'');
```

is there a way to removed them without using regex?
because regex is prone to ddos,

base on sonarqube.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-5852

Comment: Your regex looks safe and performant to me.  You should change your SonarQube filter, which is too sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but i came with this :

```
const test = "0032540140043000";
const removeTrailingZeros = (str) => {
  let result = `${+str}`;
  while (result.at(-1) === "0") {
    result = result.slice(0, -1);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(removeTrailingZeros(test)); // 32540140043
```

Explanation : `+str` remove the leading "0" when parsing a string to a number, because JS prefers `123` than `0123`.
Then, a little loop to remove the trailing "0" on this string. Then, return the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use regex, then you will have to iterate the string character by character from both ends.  Actually, if you use a regex alternation it is a good and concise option:

```
sample.toString().replace(/^0+|0+$/g, "");
```

Comment: yeah but it's prone to ddos attack base on sonarcube.
https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-5852

Comment: You should add more code and data.  You might want to change your SonarQube settings.  Your link mentions catastrophic backtracking, not DOS.